# Readline is skipping the first line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to write a simple application that will translate `ethereum` private keys to wallet addresses. My issue is, `readline` seems to skip the first line in my source file and when it reaches the end of source file it inserts blank line so programs gets exception because key format is invalid (makes sense because its empty). If I can somehow shift this 1 up I think it would resolve my issue.

```
import os
from ethereum import utils

filepath = input('enter source:')
with open(filepath) as fp:
    line = fp.readline()
    destination = input('enter destination:')
    while line:
        line = fp.readline()
        line = line.strip('\n')
        rawAddress = utils.privtoaddr(line)
        accAddress = utils.checksum_encode(rawAddress)
        f = open(destination, "a")
        f.write(accAddress + "\n")
        f.close()
```

Edit: to rule out the ethereum library i rewrote the application to simnply open a file that has 1 line in it and write it to another. same result, the destination will be empty. if there are 2 lines in source there will be 1 line in destination. What am i missing?

```
   import os
   filepath = '/home/linadmin/Desktop/pkeys.small.log'
   with open(filepath, "r") as fp:
       line = fp.readline()
       while line:
           line = fp.readline()
           f = open("/home/linadmin/Desktop/processed.log", "a")
           f.write(line)
           f.close()
```

Comment: readline does not skip the first line ... the answer must be something else... but it looks like you read the first line and then dont do anything with it before you read the second line

Comment: Wanted to help, so began installing ethereum... boy it's a big module.

Comment: It's not `readline()`, but you can (should) be using `for line in fp:` anyway.

Comment: You can try readlines()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the first statement in the loop is `line = fp.readline()`. So you're discarding the line that you read before the loop, and setting `line` to the next line.

You can simply move that statement to the end of the loop instead of the beginning.

```
with open(filepath) as fp:
    line = fp.readline()
    destination = input('enter destination:')
    while line:
        line = line.strip('\n')
        rawAddress = utils.privtoaddr(line)
        accAddress = utils.checksum_encode(rawAddress)
        with open(destination, "a") as f:
            f.write(accAddress + "\n")
        line = fp.readline()
```

Or instead, you can get rid of all the `readline()` calls, and use a `for` loop

```
with open(filepath) as fp:
    destination = input('enter destination:')
    for line in fp:
        line = line.strip('\n')
        rawAddress = utils.privtoaddr(line)
        accAddress = utils.checksum_encode(rawAddress)
        with open(destination, "a") as f:
            f.write(accAddress + "\n")
```

Comment: This is excellent. makes perfect sense to me. Thank you for your time, i sincerely appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You simply discarded the first line from `fp.readline()` which explains the "skip". `readline` returns an empty string at end of file which explains the exception (mostly - you also may want to account for lines that only have a new line). This is a simple line-by-line read of the file which is handled with a for loop.

This should do what you want

```
import os
from ethereum import utils

filepath = input('enter source:')
destination = input('enter destination:')
with open(filepath) as fp, open(destination, 'w') as out_fp:
    for line in fp:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue
        rawAddress = utils.privtoaddr(line)
        accAddress = utils.checksum_encode(rawAddress)
        out_fp.write(accAddress + "\n")
```